# Create Class Level Properties in Protege

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

Is it possible to create a property in Protege that relates two classes? `P` would be an instance of `rdf:Property` and a sibling to `rdfs:subClassOf`. `P` would have domain and range `rdfs:Class` just like `rdfs:subClassOf`. This is trivial to do in TopBraidComposer but does not seem possible in Protege.

Comment: Not possible in OWL 2 DL. However, read about *punning*: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning